# Simple.Data Lazy Reference Null

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lazy-loading, simple.data

I'm querying a table (Jobs) that has 3 records.  The table has a Foreign Key to JobTypes and to a table called Users.  When running the following query I get three records back, but I can only lazy load for the first returned result.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> jobs = _db.Jobs.All()
            .Where(_db.Jobs.Completed == false)
            .Where(_db.Jobs.RunAfter <= DateTime.Now);

Console.Out.WriteLine("Jobs Found: {0}", jobs.ToList().Count);

foreach(var job in jobs.ToList())
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} from {1}", job.JobType.Name, job.User.Username); 
}
```

The output is:

```
Jobs Found: 3
Some Job by admin
```

And the error message is:
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

At the time of the error, using quickwatch job.JobType and job.User are both null but the job.JobType_Id and job.User_Id properties both have a valid guid as a value.

The error occurs on the second iteration in the foreach loop.  All jobs currently have the same user id but a different job type id.  I have verified the ids are correct in each table.  Any ideas of what could be causing this error during lazy loading?

Comment: Which Simple.Data provider are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? etc

Comment: I'm using the SQL Server provider.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add **MultipleActiveResultSets=true** in your config file?

Comment: Yes.  Although I did not have to do that when referencing lazy loaded properties in an MVC view.  This issue has only happened to me with this console app.